# Identify which div is scrolled to the top

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a data attribute of each div with class .section which has reached/scrolled to the top. But somehow the only first div is getting identified even other ones are scrolled to the top.

Please see the example below.

```js
var distance = $('.section').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() >= distance ) {
        console.log($('.section').data("action"));
    }
});
```

```css
.section {height:600px;border-top:solid 1px black}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" data-action="one"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="two"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="three"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="four"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="five"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? or maybe it can guide you to make it:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.section').each(function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('data-action');
    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
      console.log(action)
    }
  });
});

$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

Ref to [code](https://medium.com/talk-like/detecting-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-jquery-a6a4405a3ea2)

**Demo**

```js
var distance = $('.section').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.section').each(function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('data-action');

    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
      if ($(this).attr("data-view") == "false") {
        console.log(action);
        $(this).attr("data-view", true)
      }
    } else {
      $(this).attr("data-view", false);
    }
  });
});

$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

```css
.section {
  height: 600px;
  border-top: solid 1px black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" data-action="one"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="two"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="three"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="four"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="five"> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to fire event for each .section only ones as soon as it reached the top not along the scroll further down.

Comment: @qqruza try the demo now, its a little buggy with the first div because it's already inside the viewport.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much my friend.

Comment: @qqruza No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var distance = $('.section').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() >= distance ) {
        console.log($('.section')); // This returns an array of multiple divs. You need to iterate through it for getting the desired output.
        console.log($('.section').data("action"));
    }
});
```

```css
.section {height:600px;border-top:solid 1px black}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" data-action="one"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="two"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="three"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="four"> </div>
<div class="section" data-action="five"> </div>
```